Images not displaying in Gmail - Gmail adding stuff to my img src
We are generating emails in code, and attaching a logo for the company. We have tested it on several email hosts, but when gmail recieves these emails, the logo doesn't display.
Upon further inspection, it seems this is because Gmail is adding https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/[some stuff] to the front of our image host, so it looks like
<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/etcetcetcetc#https://our.imagehost.com/img/logo.svg"...>
Does anyone know why gmail does this and why it leads to the image not showing (just showing the broken jpg thumb), as well as how to fix?
Here is the code to send the email:
     public void SendEmail(string subject, string from, string to, string body)
 {

     var mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
     {
         From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from),
         Subject = subject,
         Body = body,
         IsBodyHtml = true
     };

     mm.To.Add(to);


     using (var ret = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
     {
         
         ret.Host = SmtpConfig.Host; 
         ret.Port = SmtpConfig.Port;
         ret.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpConfig.User, SmtpConfig.Password);
         ret.EnableSsl = SmtpConfig.EnableSsl;


         ret.Send(mm);
     };


 }


Is gmail set to HTML mode or Text mode.  Often issue is caused because the email server is defaulting to Text instead of HTML.  It may be some mail server are set default to text.  You may be able to solve issue when generating the email by adding the Content-Type to the http headers in the message.

welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example]
